# python, write a code to automatically execute an external program and use the method to execute the program's task

Tags: python

I want to run my external (.exe) program on window using python. in order to run a specific task of that program(the .exe) , i need to know the method and call in inside my test.py (my python file), how do i call a function in my python?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\EnergyPlusV7-2-0\EP-Launch.exe', 'C:\\modelo_0001.idf'])
```

now i need to call a method through python to run a specific task on the external program(the .exe file), but how? can someone give me an example format? there s a button say 'simulate', i need to get the method for that button so that i can execute it through python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use pywinauto for that: http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/
Install it and read docs.

example:

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application.start("C:\\EnergyPlusV7-2-0\\EP-Launch.exe")
# open dialog here with pywinauto (see docs), it's bound to interface can't help here
# press next button
```

Also look into SWAPY it will generate automation python code for pywinauto.

http://code.google.com/p/swapy/